# RuntimeError: could not open display

Tags: python, pygtk, tox

I have a unit test which contains

```
import gtk
```

Which contains unit tests to test the signal handler and GUI classes. This works fine when I run `py.test` from the shell as I have an X11 display connected. However, when I try to run tox, I get:

```
______________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_gui.py ______________________
tests/test_gui.py:17: in <module>
    from rprs_bootstrap.gui import GUI
src/gui.py:12: in <module>
    import gtk.glade
.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:64: in <module>
    _init()
.tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:52: in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
E   RuntimeError: could not open display
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.34 seconds ============================
make: *** [tox] Error 2
```

I could start a [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) server from within `tox.ini` but that seems inelegant.  *Any suggestions?*

Comment: pytests-xvfb seems nice as you mention in your answer, but why do you consider running your tests with Xvfb inelegant?

Comment: @bohrax: It involves installing system wide packages that not all developers might have. It's yet another freaking dependency waiting to mess things up like some evil imp with mischief in its gleaming dead uncaring eyes.

Comment: I first had the exact same mental objection WRT pytests-xvfb :-), but I guess that the advantage is that you can treat pytests-xvfb as a part of the controlled dev environment as opposed to a "system wide" package even though you need Xvfb installed to really use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pytest-xvfb](https://github.com/The-Compiler/pytest-xvfb)

which

> [...] runs your testsuite with Xvfb to avoid popping up windows during
>   GUI tests or allow them to run on systems without a display (like a
>   CI).

To install:

```
pip install pytest-xvfb
```